# Fetch parent of a specific row in a table without iteration

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver

Consider the below table structure contains many rows with multiple column values. I need to identify the parent of specific row, which has to be identified using the cell .

```
<table class = 'grid'>
<thead id = 'header'>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
 <span class="group">
  <span class="group__link"><a class="disabledlink"">copy</a>
  </span>
 </span>
 </td>
 <td class="COLUMNNAME">ACE</td>
 <td class="COLUMNLONGNAME">Adverse Childhood Experiences</td>
    <li>Family Medicine</li>
    <li>General Practice</li>
 </td>
 <td class="COLUMNSEXFILTER">Both</td>
 <td class="COLUMNAGEFILTERMIN">Any</td>
 <td class="COLUMNTYPE">Score Only</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="nowrap" showactionitem="2">
 <span class="group">
  <span class="group__link"><a onclick="Check()" href="#">copy</a>
  </span>
 </span>
 </td>
 <td class="COLUMNNAME">AM-PAC</td>
 <td class="COLUMNLONGNAME">AM-PAC Generic Outpatient Basic Mobility Short Form</td>
 <td class="COLUMNNOTE"></td>
 <td class="COLUMNRESTRICTEDYN">No</td>
 <td class="COLUMNSPECIALTYID"></td>
 <td class="COLUMNSEXFILTER">Both</td>
 <td class="COLUMNAGEFILTERMIN">Any</td>
 <td class="COLUMNTYPE">Score Only</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</tbody></thead>
</table>
```

Likewise this table contains around 100 rows. I did the same using iteration and it is working fine.
Is it possible to find the parent of specific row without iteration?

Comment: Do you want to get locate the row using cell?

Comment: Can you add your coding as well for reference?

Comment: When you say "parent of specific row" are you trying to get the `tr` element containing the cell or the parent of the `tr` that contains the cell? The wording suggests the latter, but I would think you want the former?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `parent` method to find the parent of an element. Assuming that you have located a table cell, let's call it `cell`, you can get its row using `parent` and then the parent of the row with another call to `parent`:

```
cell.parent
#=> a <tr> element

cell.parent.parent
#=> the parent of the specific row - a <tbody> element in this case
```

Chaining multiple `parent` calls can become tedious and difficult to maintain. For example, you would have to call `parent` 4 times to get the table cell of the "copy" link. If you are after an ancestor (ie not immediate parent), you are better off using XPath:

```
cell.table(xpath: './ancestor::table')
#=> the <table> element containing the cell

browser.link(text: 'copy').tr(xpath: './ancestor::tr')
#=> the <tr> element containing a copy link
```

Hopefully [Issue 451](https://github.com/watir/watir/pull/451) will be implemented soon, which will remove the need for XPath. You would be able to call:

```
cell.parent(tag_name: 'table') # equivalent to `cell.table(xpath: './ancestor::table')`
```

Comment: This is now implemented in Watir 6.2! http://watir.github.io/watir-6-2/ No More XPath!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for anything fancy, Watir has an `Element#parent` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

**parent::node()**

The below example will selects the parent node of the input tag of Id='email'.
Ex: **//input[@id='email']/parent::***

the above can also be re-written as
**//input[@id='email']/..**

[XPath tutorial for Selenium](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium)